# Measuring time in the photoelectric effect

Tags: special-relativity, time-dilation, resonance, photoelectric-effect

Consider the following hypothetical:

An atom is traveling with a velocity of v to the left, directly towards an incoming photon, as crudely depicted below.

p----> <----A

**Question (1): What is the resonance absorption frequency of the atom?**

**Question (2): What is the threshold frequency of the atom?**

Question (1) requires that we assume that time-dilation is occurring within the atom, in order to be consistent with experimental evidence that shows that the resonance absorption frequency of an atom does in fact decrease due to time-dilation.

[Kundig Experiment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ives%E2%80%93Stilwell_experiment#M%C3%B6ssbauer_rotor_experiments)

Question (2) requires that we assume that time-dilation is NOT occurring within the atom, in order to be consistent with the equations for the work function of an electron, which, as far as I can tell, assume that time-dilation is not occurring.

[Electron Work Function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Photoelectric_effect#Mathematical_description)

This seems to imply that there is no single answer to "how much time has elapsed" as measured within the atom, since (1) and (2), by definition, require different measurements of time.

What is the correct measure of time in this set of facts?